# Dropdown fields will not populate

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

Long-time listener, first-time caller.

I am attempting to learn from other posted examples, but it does not seem to be working out for me.
Using examples I have found, I am trying to create a 4-tiered cascading dropdown menu.  My problem is that the menus will not populate.  I am receiving the following errors:

> PHP Warning:  mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/mstarks/public_html/TEST/STUFF/ddmenu.php on line 36
>
> PHP Warning:  mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/mstarks/public_html/TEST/STUFF/ddmenu.php on line 44

All of the queries run fine using PhPAdmin.

Here is the code:

```
<script language=JavaScript>
function reload(form)
    {
        var selected_value=form.man.options[form.man.options.selectedIndex].value;
        self.location='ddmenu.php?man=' + selected_value ;   
    }
</script>

<?php
@$man=$HTTP_GET_VARS['man'];
if(strlen($man) > 0 and !is_numeric($man))
    { 
        echo "INVALID DATA.";
        exit;
    }
 
$divisions_query=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT division, division_id FROM employees_division ORDER BY division_id"); 
 
if(isset($man) and strlen($man) > 0)
    {
        $bureaus_query=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT bureau FROM employees_bureau WHERE division_id=$man ORDER BY bureau_id"); 
    }
        else
    {
        $bureaus_query=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT bureau FROM employees_bureau ORDER BY bureau_id");
    } 
 
echo "<form method=post name=f1 action='ddmenu2.php'>";

echo "<select name='man' onchange=\"reload(this.form)\"><option value=''>Select Division</option>";
while($qresult_divisions=mysql_fetch_array($divisions_query)) 
    { 
        if($qresult_divisions['division_id']==@$man){echo "<option selected value='$qresult_divisions[division_id]'>$qresult_divisions[division]</option>"."<BR>";}
        else{echo  "<option value='$qresult_divisions[division_id]'>$qresult_divisions[division]</option>";}
    }
echo "</select>";

echo "<select name='mod'><option value=''>Select Bureau</option>";
while($qresult_bureaus=mysql_fetch_array($bureaus_query)) 
    { 
        echo  "<option value='$qresult_bureaus[bureau]'>$qresult_bureaus[bureau]</option>";
    }
echo "</select>";

echo "<input type=submit value=Submit>";
echo "</form>";
?>
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would be most grateful.  I still need to add two more dropdowns for this thing, then figure out how to add it to an existing page.

I have seen info on using AJAX, but that is way over my head.  I have to make do with javascript and PHP.

If I did not format this question correctly, please excuse.  First post here and I haven't quite figured it out yet.

Comment: What line is `36` and `44`?

Comment: You should really switch to `mysqli`, mysql is outdated

Comment: Did you connect to the MySQL database? And as said above take a look at [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/mysqli) because MySQL is now deprecated.

Comment: Those errors mean that the DB did not return results and therefore the function can't work properly.  After running your `SELECT` queries you should `echo` the contents of MySQL's error message to help figure out why you didn't get a result.  Also, consider using [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/mysqli) as the mysql_* batch of functions is deprecated.

Comment: As per @Crackertastic, select query returns nothing. First run same query in Database and correct it. Then go ahead with this code. or try with **mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error())**

Comment: @Arian, Lines 36 and 44 are the WHILE statements, used to fetch the arrays.
I know that mysql is depreciated, I intend to rework all of the pages at a later date.  This site is only used on a closed network, so I am not overly concerned with security.

Comment: @Kishore -- All queries run fine against the database.

Comment: I am such a putz!!!

Thanks to everyone for chiming in.  After reading the comments, I realized that I was not connecting to the database.
I added a my_select_db line and things started working.  
Old people can learn new things I guess.
Thanks again everyone.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query` is failing and returning FALSE. This causes your `$divisions_query` variable to be set to `FALSE` instead of an array that you are expecting. The errors you are getting are because `mysql_fetch_array()` expects an array, not `FALSE`. Try using a check statement like this.

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * WHERE 1=1');
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
?>
```

More info found at: http://www.php.net/mysql_query

Good Luck!